# Port forwarding from IP to localhost?

Tags: routes, nat, osx-yosemite

How can I make all traffic sent to an IP address (192.168.91.164) be forwarded to localhost, or another host within my local network? Note my machine is on a 10.0.1.x network.

I am trying to do this on a Mac OS Yosemite, which uses `pf` as a firewall and has no `ipfw` or `iptables`.

More specifically, I have a process that connects to an ActiveMQ server on 192.168.91.164 port 8161 (I can't change this address or port), but I would like it to connect an ActiveMQ server on my local machine on the same port, or another host on my local network.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to edit your `/etc/hosts` and then redirect the IP to **127.0.0.1**

Edit this file with any text editor and add this line to the end:

```
127.0.0.1       192.168.91.164
```